# Rendering partial from another folder from another partial in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial

For example:
I'm have two models: `Task` and `List`. `Task` `belongs_to` `List`.
I'm render `lists/_form.html.erb` partial within `lists/show.html.erb view`.
Now I need to render `tasks/_fields.html.erb` partial within `lists/_form.html.erb` partial:

```
<%= render 'tasks/fields' %>
```

But I get an error `ActionView::MissingTemplate`

If I try to render `tasks/_fields.html.erb` within `lists/_form.html.erb`, everything works.

I see two bad ways to solve this problem:

- Place `_fields.html.erb` to `lists` folder
- Make a view from `lists/_form.html.erb` partial and try a "Nested Layouts" from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Is there a good way?

Answer (score 46):

Try this:

```
<%= render :partial => 'tasks/fields' %>
```

Answer (score 7):

**For Rails 5 & above**:

You better use the render without partial like this:

```
<% render 'tasks/fields' %>
```

Because the `partial` can cause this [kind of issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480841/rails-cant-pass-variable-to-partial-what-am-i-doing-wrong) & is not needed any more

Answer (score 6):

If you are sharing things like this, why not put them into a folder like `app/views/shared/` or directly into `app/views/layouts`?

Comment: Because it logically belongs to `Task` model

Answer (score 5):

Based on @ArunKumarArjun but with the new Rails notation:

```
<%= render partial: 'tasks/fields' %>
```