# Rails: can't pass variable to partial, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, parameter-passing, partials

I'm trying a few different ways to define and pass the local variable to the partial, but it keeps saying it's undefined:

in Show file:

```
<% @startups.each do |startup| %>
  <%= render :partial => "profile/startup" %>
<% end %>
```

in partial:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@commentable, @comment], :remote => true do |form| %>
  <%= form.input :content, label: false, :input_html => { :id => "#{startup.user_id}" } %>
  <%= form.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

These are the other ways I'm trying to pass the variable, but still getting undefined:

```
<%= render :partial => "user_comments/uac",  object: startup, as: startup %>
<%= render :partial => "user_comments/uac",  collection: startup, as: startup %>
<%= render :partial => "user_comments/uac", :locals => {:startup => startup} %>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get rid of `:partial`. You haven't needed that in Rails for several versions.

The correct way of passing a local called `startup` to a partial is this:

```
render "profile/startup", startup: startup
```

Comment: I keep getting this "
`undefined local variable or method `startup`'` :/ ?

Comment: Thank you so much I had two lines in my code later I found out the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I was facing a similar problem. Rails is confusing.